# Selenium, Capybara: Resize Window does not reach the right resolution

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, capybara, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Capybara with chrome and I want to resize the window to a specific resolution, in my case 1920*1080.

For this I am using the *resize_to* function with the parameters above.

But the Window is rather maximized, than the expected resolution is reached. Maybe it is a problem with me working on a mac?
But what can I do, that i **always** have the proper resolution, and not just a maximized Window?

Comment: When I try a higher resolution I get the following error:
_Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError Exception: unknown error: failed to change window state to normal, current state is maximized_

How can I set a higher resolution, than "maximized" ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the resolution to higher than your screen resolution.

Comment: I see but this behaviour is kind of stupid. Right now I set the resolution on 1920x1080. When I use chrome headless the resolution is exactly used. When I use a normal chrome browser, the resolution is randomly at 1920x863 - 867. This is not useful, but logically correct hence I am working on a mac and thats the maximal possible window resolution. But I want a static value, no randomness

Comment: If you want a static value when running with the windows displayed (not headless)  then you need to specify a valid size that you know the system can support (for instance try 1920x800 if your display supports that)